# Fastest option to check whether user is logged in on firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm currently checking whether a user is logged in client-side using:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user)
{
}
```

However, this method takes 1-2 seconds after the page has loaded to be called and I was wondering whether there was a faster way to check if the user is signed in?

I'm using this to check that the user is authorised to enter a specific page on a website, and at the moment they are able to view the contents of it before being redirected to the homepage, which shouldn't happen. So I am hoping for a faster alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method that i was using to execute certain code immediately after the user logged (avoid waiting by executing a fast loop that keeps testing for the user data)  :

```js
var int = setInterval(()=>{
 firebase.auth().currentUser ?
 // you can do whatever you want immediately when the user is logged
 // and then clear the interval;
 clearInterval(int) 
 : '' 
  }
},10)
```

Comment: How long would this take on average to execute? I was curious as I don't know how much of a difference this will make rather than to just use an observer.

Comment: @danwillm it's not sync so on average it will take much less than just using the normal request ....one other advantage with this method is that you can access pages only when the user is logged (available data) instead of getting errors / also you can clear the interval after the duration you want using a counter if the user data doesn't exist ...